# Ajax call failed only on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I have an ajax call for login:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url_to_ajax,
        success: function ( data ) {
            switch (data) {
                case "-2": input1.addClass("has-error");
                    break;
                case "-1": input1.addClass("has-error");
                    break;
                case "0": input2.addClass("has-error");
                    break;
                case "1": //everythings ok
                        window.location.replace(base_url);
                    break;
                default: //this should not happens
                        window.location.replace(base_url);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

And chrome console gives me this:

```
GET http://testserv.local/profil/login_call/admin@gmail.com/ross 404 (Not Found)
```

When I copy this URL in browser, everythings is ok and it shows me result code. On live server is everything ok. But on localhost this.. And for me, the biggest mistery is, that the url is called with that ajax, because after refresh page I'm logged in..

Can someone help me?

I am using wamp, Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12 on windows 8.1

EDIT: I was writing this code a month before, everythings were ok on live and on localhost.. After I formated disc and install new W8.1 this code doesn't work.

Comment: `everythings is ok and it shows me result code.` and what is that result code? IMHO your code is little bit specific, usually you should just `success: function ( data ) {
            switch (data) {
                  window.location.replace(base_url);

            }` but I never saw your php code, so maybe your js code has some sense

Comment: Result code just from php echo something

Comment: what is your something?? is it `-2`? `-1`? `0`? `1`? if you see something that doesn't mean that response is 200 OK

Comment: yes, result from php is -2, -1, 0 and 1.. but I don't understand why the same code works on live server, but on localhost not

Comment: so what is YOUR result on the screen? on localhost???

Comment: If i put the url "http://youshort.local/profil/login_call/rosskodca@gmail.com/ross" in browser i see "1" (which is ok), but if I set the same url to ajax, chrome console shows me 404
(youshort.local is the same as testserv.local I just change name of srv)

Comment: the only guess I can imaging is @ character. so your `data` is empty? just `url_to_ajax` counts? so where is `url_to_ajax` initialization? do you do `encodeURIComponent` for email?

Comment: no, but as i said, on live server the same code (just changed youshort.local to live url) works perfectly.. i don't have any idea why it doesn't work on local.. is there any chance to have some bad configuration in php.ini or something ? for example some module.. ?

Comment: the live one http either? not https ?

Comment: yes, http (htaccess is the same too)

Comment: could you `console.log(url_to_ajax);` please? byt the way, even if `youshort.local is the same as testserv.local` they still not equal `youshort.local != testserv.local` you should use same domain when request

Comment: Now I am trying it only on youshort.local
i put console.log on url_to_ajax before ajax and into success function (console.log("success");)..
Chrome console after it:
http://youshort.local/profil/login_call/rosskodca@gmail.com/ro
GET http://youshort.local/profil/login_call/rosskodca@gmail.com/ro 404 (Not Found)

the url is ok, somewhere else should be problem

Comment: ??? so you did console log, show the oputput please!by the way I didn't ask for concole - success, I've asked for value of `url_to_ajax`

Comment: I did it, but bad formating.. here is img from console http://drosapp.eu/consolelog.png and this http://drosapp.eu/network.png is from network card.. but still if i put the url in browser it shows me result 1 or something, but not 404 Page not found

Comment: hey, you did `console.log(url_to_ajax);` and got img there? isn't it interesting?

Comment: Don't you see it in that img? First line! I send you img for comparation url_to_ajax and GET 404 url

Comment: I whould try `concat(encodeURIComponent();`  https://ideone.com/Xzy4N4 that has a little sense, if you have no other guess

Comment: could you show not only 404 headers, but response tab in chrom console either?

Comment: doesn't work at all too.. some magic happened probably..

Comment: In response tab is: 0
Which is answer from php and it's right

Comment: F*** this s*** .. Answer on this sh*t is put: header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); in that code.. Oh, god, why? 6 hourse resolving this sh*t.. thank you for your help anyway !

Answer (score 1):

After 6 hours i resolved it.. Just put

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

In your code if you have the same "magic" problem as me..

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with AJAX, but with the server.

The error that you're getting is 404 Not Found. That means that the web server at "testserv.local" exists and is responding, but couldn't find the resource you're looking for. Have you made any change to the local server, recently? What happens if you open `http://testserv.local/profil/login_call/admin@gmail.com/ross` on your browser? And what about each of:

```
http://testserv.local/profil/login_call/admin@gmail.com
http://testserv.local/profil/login_call/
http://testserv.local/profil/
http://testserv.local/
```

(I am asking this because if you're using those urls, maybe the mod_rewrite in Apache stopped working because you changed some configuration)

Comment: If I put this in browser it shows me result from php code and it is right but ajax dont accept this url

Comment: Can you post your PHP code? And the full output from Chrome?

Comment: In PHP is only:
echo $this->user->login(($user_name_email), ($user_password));

which returns: -2, -1, 0, or 1 which are states (bad login, bad email, bad passwrd, everythings ok)
 Chrome:
GET http://youshort.local/profil/login_call/rosskodca@gmail.com/ross 404 (Not Found)
m.ajaxTransport.send
m.extend.ajax
 (anonymous function)
m.event.dispatch
m.event.add.r.handle

Comment: Do you see that Chrome is calling "youshort.local"?

Comment: Yes, is ok, i changed it, testserv.local is the same as youshort.local